# Android ADB: pull to memory

Tags: java, android, adb

Is it possible to somehow redirect the outputs of adb pull not to a file but to some place in memory?

specifically i am writing a java program, that executes

```
adb pull /dev/graphics/fb0
```

and in the same program i want to process the results without having to read the `fb0` file from disk again.

Answer (score 1):

You can make sure to write the file into shared memory.
Assuming your using a linux system just pull the file into the

/dev/shm/ directory.

See this post for more details.

http://www.howtoforge.com/storing-files-directories-in-memory-with-tmpfs

Comment: sounds interesting but i am using windows

Answer (score 1):

You can always do something like

```
adb shell cat /dev/graphics/fb0 | myprogramthatprocessestheresult
```

and you don't have to save the file as long as `myprogramthatprocessestheresult` reads from stdin.